# Debugger showing wrong values

Tags: android, list, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

Am trying to work with `Fragments` and this question might seem stupid, but now i have encountered one problem.

Am trying to list the `Fragments` in a `List` , the list is having more number of fragment that it is showing, the size is accurate but values are wrong.

[image]

But when i try to get the last Fragment from the list even though the list size is `greater than 0`. The fragment is returning as `null`

[image]

i am posting Screenshots just to clarify the returned value and size of the list.

Why is this happening? Is something wrong with Android Studio?

I even checked whether fragments are back stacked properly, but i was working fine. Just cant figure out why this is happening.

`returnFragment` function is written on `Activity` extending `AppCompatActivity`

Any kind of help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Arraylist has size 4. Only the first two values are not null. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you able to get Fragment by calling fragsList.get(0) or fragsList.get(1) ?

Comment: (psst, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334986/rejection-reason-response-to-documentation-or-a-question-about-the-documentatio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because there's actually 4 entries in the fragment list, but the two of the entries are turning out to be a `null` object, so the debugger is not showing,

As you are getting the fragment object is `null` so its obvious that these entries are null.